# How to extract type out of observable<type> in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to create a utility class which will have all the common functions used among components. Below is the code

```
import { Component, OnInit }  from 'angular2/core';
import { CommonService } from './services/common.service';
import { Observable }  from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
    providers: [CommonService]
})

export class Utils {

    constructor(private _commonService: CommonService) { }

    getColumnNames(database: string, tableName: string): string[] {
        return this._commonService.getColumnNames(database, tableName).subscribe(data => this.promise(data));
    }

    private promise(data: string[]) {
        return data;
    }
}
```

The common service return `Observable<string[]>` and I want to extract `string[]` out of the `observable<string[]>`. I know I can create a private promise to retrieve it but then how would I send it back to the calling function in the components.

Comment: Your code declares that it returns `string[]` and not `Observable<string[]>`, which is wrong. Also, what exactly do you mean by "extract string[]"?

Comment: I want to return the "data" in the promise from getColumnNames. As simple as that.

Comment: You can not return any data from your `getColumnNames` as it performs an asynchronous operation and the data isn't available yet when the function returns. You can/should return an observable or a promise to that data, and who ever calls this method will then need to subscribe on that observable.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I didn't realize that. I just wanted to return the final result instead of making the function create their own promise and extract the result.